# Is it safe to retrieve credentials such as clientId, secret, etc. from an API?

Tags: api, design-patterns, credentials

I'm currently running an online community, we're now launching another community and actually intend to launch several over the course of the next months. Each community has their own auth0 client, as well as other settings such as, which features are activated per community, what are their Twitter/FB accounts, which API should it connect to, etc.

Right now this is still hardcoded, now I'm thinking to retrieve this all via API but I'm not sure how safe this to retrieve these all from the client? Ultimately these things end up in the client anyway via the node environment variables, so it shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: you can fetch it but use token based authentication for this.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? I get what token based authentication is, we already are using it for our API, though I'm not sure what would I authenticate against? 

As a non-yet signed up user for example, I want to retrieve the features (to show in the navigation) even if I'm not yet logged in.